# Min and max index of values in list of lists

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have a 3D list of lists, whose items can be any of a finite selection:

`list_of_lists = [[[0, 0], [0, 1]], [[0, 0], [1, 1]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]]`

I would like to determine the minimum and maximum index in all 3 dimensions of each occurring item.

(I do not want to find the index of the minimum and maximum item, which seems to be a more frequent question.)

The output should be:

```
# value: [min_x, max_x, min_y, max_y, min_z, max_z]
0: [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2]
1: [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1] # 1 does not occur in any list #0 of second dimension and not in list #2 of the highest dimension
```

where x refers to the lowest dimension of the list of lists, y refers to the second dimension and z refers to the highest dimension.

Comment: somehow hard to understand, maybe for me ! where did that `2` come from ?

Comment: The list of lists has length 3 in the highest dimension, i.e. indices are 0, 1, 2. The value 0 occurs in all 3 highest-order sub-lists of the list of lists (in list_of_lists[0], list_of_lists[1] and list_of_lists[2], whose min is 0 and max is 2). Think of the 3D list of lists as a coordinate grid; I want to find the coordinates of those parallelepipeds that embrace each of the values in the list of lists.

Comment: I think you have your dimensions backwards. The shape of `list_of_lists` is (3, 2, 2), not (2, 2, 3), using NumPy conventions.

Comment: It might be confusing that I used the values 0 and 1 in the list of lists; they can be replaced by any other values whereas in the two output lists 0, 1 and 2 are indices.

Comment: @wjandrea I do not see the point. z runs from 0 to 2 (len 3), x and y run from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I am doing this now (sorry, no complete code here because this would comprise a larger number of lines that do not add information to the problem). However, the code is terribly little idiomatic.

indices_min_max is a dict whose keys are the values from the list of lists and whose respective values are initialized as None.

The code iterates over the single items of the list of lists and x_value, y_value and z_value are the coordinates of each item in the 3 dimensions.

```
if indices_min_max[value] == None:
    indices_min_max[value] = [x_value, x_value, y_value, y_value, z_value, z_value]
else:
    if x_value < indices_min_max[value][0]:
        organs_min_max_dict[value][0] = x_value

    if x_value > indices_min_max[value][1]:
        organs_min_max_dict[value][1] = x_value

    if y_value < indices_min_max[value][2]:
        organs_min_max_dict[value][2] = y_value

    if y_value > indices_min_max[value][3]:
        organs_min_max_dict[value][3] = y_value

    if z_value < indices_min_max[value][4]:
        organs_min_max_dict[value][4] = z_value

    if z_value > indices_min_max[value][5]:
        organs_min_max_dict[value][5] = z_value
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have your dimensions backwards. The shape of your `list_of_lists` is (3, 2, 2), not (2, 2, 3) (at least in the system I'm used to, which is used in NumPy for example).

Secondly, interleaving the min and max is really confusing to me, so I'm going to arrange the desired output differently:

```
{0: {'min': [0, 0, 0], 'max': [2, 1, 1]},
 1: {'min': [0, 1, 0], 'max': [1, 1, 1]}}
```

On the other hand, you might find interleaving the dimensions confusing, which is perfectly valid.

Lastly, this solution might be relatively slow if your actual data is very long. In that case, look into using NumPy to make it faster. The solution would probably end up being cleaner anyway since NumPy is specifically designed for multidimensional data.

---

Use [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get indices along each axis, and compare each coordinate to the previously saved min/max value.

```
list_of_lists = [
    [[0, 0], [0, 1]],
    [[0, 0], [1, 1]],
    [[0, 0], [0, 0]]]

d = {}
props = {'min': min, 'max': max}  # Properties we're looking for
for x, row in enumerate(list_of_lists):
    for y, col in enumerate(row):
        for z, elem in enumerate(col):
            c = (x, y, z)
            if elem not in d:
                d[elem] = {p: list(c) for p in props}
                continue

            for p, f in props.items():
                L = d[elem][p]
                L[:] = (f(old, new) for old, new in zip(L, c))
```